# Blending two data sources with dates properly

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to make a chart that displays our "cost per scheduled call" on our looker dashboard. The calculation is: [The Amount Spent on The Facebook Ad] / [The Number of Scheduled Calls From The Ad]. To do this we need to use two data sources:

1. Our Data From Facebook Ads, where we have many fields including "Ad Name", "Date", and "Amount Spent"
2. Our CRM Data, which has fields including "Created Date", "UTM Content" (Same as "Ad Name"), and "DidScheduleCall" (1 if yes, 0 if no)

To do this right now I'm blending the two data sources on "Ad Name" and "Date" - which works - sort of. The problem is that there are some days when we have ad spend but no entries in our CRM, which leads to the ad spend being labeled as "null" instead of relating to a specific ad, under-counting the amount spent in the calculation. For example the data might look like:

Facebook Data
Date | Ad Name | Amount Spent
20230601 | My Great Ad | $10
20230602 | My Great Ad | $10
20230603 | My Great Ad | $10

CRM Data
Created Date | UTM Content | DidScheduleCall
20230601 | My Great Ad | 0
20230601 | My Great Ad | 1
20230602 | My Great Ad | 1
20230602 | My Great Ad | 1
20230602 | My Great Ad | 0

In this case notice that CRM Data does not have an entry for 20230603, which will result in:

Ad Name | Amount Spent | DidScheduleCall | Cost Per Scheduled Call
My Great Ad | $20 | 3 | $6.67
null | $10 | 0 | null

I think we need a different approach. Any ideas on how to make this work properly?

I've included some screenshots in case it helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the expected output(test scenario) be: *My Great Ad | 30 | 3 | 10*